# Interchange Foreground and Background Colors when highlighting selected text

Tags: faces, colors, region, highlighting

I use something like this to control the background color of my selected text:

```
(region ((t (:background ,green))
            (t :inverse-video t)))
```

However some foreground colors don't go well with my background color and the text becomes hard to read. So I experimented with different background colors for `region`, but the results have not been satisfactory.

Now I wish for this behavior:

**Interchange the background and foreground colors on my selected text.**

The following images are for illustration of what I want:

1. Without Selection:

[image: without highlighting]

2. With Selection:

[image: with highlighting]

With this I feel, I will be able to demarcate the selected text all the while retaining my syntax highlighting along with readability.

How do I accomplish this within Emacs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps I don't understand. Just customizing face `region` to (only) use inverse-video gives you what you're asking for, as far as I can see.  So just get rid of the imposition of a green background:

[image]

Comment: That was really simple! Earlier I had tried `C-h v` to describe `inverse-video`, but I never quite understood what `inverse-video` did. A follow up question: How can I do some conditional formatting? For example I do not want inverse-video if the foreground color is white. If my foreground ground color is white I want to manually specify which foreground and background to use when highlighting selected text.

Comment: Post your follow-up question as a separate question, please.

Comment: I have posted the follow-up question [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/68760/conditional-formatting-foreground-and-background-when-highlighting-selected-text). Thanks!