# Conditional Formatting foreground and background when highlighting selected text

Tags: faces, colors, region, highlighting

This is a follow-up question to: [Interchange Foreground and Background Colors when highlighting selected text](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/68725/interchange-foreground-and-background-colors-when-highlighting-selected-text).

How can I do some conditional formatting?

For example I do not want `inverse-video` if the foreground color is white. If my foreground color is white I want to manually specify which foreground and background to use when highlighting selected text, otherwise I want to apply inverse-video.

Comment: Do you have a snippet of code you work with? Overall, the following starting points might help: [How to change custom theme](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17431/how-do-i-change-portions-of-a-custom-theme/18792#18792), [Defining Faces](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Faces.html), [more on faces](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp_define_face.html), [Custom Themes](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Custom-Themes.html), [Emacs Conditionals](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Conditionals.html)